# Pass php string as parameter for javascript function called in php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, parameters

So I have this serie of radio buttons generated by a php script that call a javascript function when they get clicked on:

```
<?php
    $databases = mysqli_query($link, "SHOW DATABASES");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($databases)) {
        $db = $row[0];
        echo "<input type='radio' name='database' id='".$db."' onclick='displaydbcontent(".$db.")'>";     
    }
?>
```

The javascript function then has to alert the content of the string:

```
function displaydbcontent(dbid) {
    alert("This is a test");
    alert(dbid);
}
```

Now, no matter what the content of the variable $db is, after displaying the first alert printing "This is a test", the second one always prints "[object HTMLInputElement]".

I am pretty sure that it's all a matter of quotation marks, but I don't see any way to work around it.

And for those who are wondering about it even thought it hasn't to do much with my issue, the $link variable has been initializated and works correctly.

Comment: Adding same id and name for different html elements in the page is not a good sense..

Comment: Because you're passing an object to the function, not a string.

Comment: The name is the same, the ID is always different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this.id` as argument which will return `id` property of the `clicked-element`

```
onclick='displaydbcontent(this.id)'>";
```

As you are passing `$db` as argument, it represents the element. Element with `id` becomes the global variables.

```js
function callMe(elem) {
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<div id='elem' onclick='callMe(elem)'>Hello!!!!!</div>
```

**Edit:** Or `echo '<input type="radio" name="database" id="'.$db.'" onclick="displaydbcontent(\'$db\')">';`

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Comment: Just to clarify, the this.id solution works, the other one doesn't since javascript quotation marks mess up with php's.